# Does oracle application express count as business intelligence tool?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working in a project which uses oracle application express.
What is the scope of oracle application express tool used?Is this a BI- tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Application Express or APEX is a general purpose tool for building data-centric web applications. [Application Express website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html)